# How setState with one value work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state, reactjs-flux

I was looking through some code while using the npm package [React-Select](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/)

Interestingly enough i saw setState being used as such:

```
handleSelectChange (value) {
        console.log('You\'ve selected:', value);
        this.setState({ value });
    },
```

How does setState work like this? It only provides one value? I am asking because I would like to perhaps capture one thing from my input and then change it. But that doesn't work as intended.

```
handleSelectChange (value) {
        console.log('You\'ve selected:', value);
        this.setState({ value.name });
    },
```

The full code is here, its fairly short: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/Multiselect.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using in ES6

```
this.setState({ value })
```

It is just a shorthand for

```
this.setState({ value: value })
```

There's nothing else magical happening here

---

For more clarity, consider this example

```js
var x = 5
var y = 10
var z = { x, y }
console.log(z)
//=> { x: 5, y: 10 }
```

---

If you want to set the state to `value.name` you would not be able to use the shorthand if the key you had to set was still called `value`

```
this.setState({ value: value.name })
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a ES2015 feature, [the property name shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). It saves you from typing the name of the key when you are assigning it the value of a variable of the same name.